# How to check check box checked or not?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html

Code not working:

```
if($('#primayins').attr('checked')) 
{    
   $("#tx_nm0x0_pricingplan").val(1); 
} 
else 
{   
   $("#tx_nm0x0_pricingplan").val(2);
}
```

Every time it is getting false

Comment: Try `.is(':checked'))` instead of `attr`

Comment: omg please the next time choose a less cryptic title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```
if($('#primayins').prop('checked')) 
...
```

Alternatively:

```
if($('#checkbox').is(':checked'))
...
```